# Android - Space between TextView and Togglebutton?

Tags: android, textview, tablerow, togglebutton

This is my code:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" > 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This Button:"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="0.9" >
    </FrameLayout> 
</TableRow>
```

When I start my app, it looks like this:

```
  This Button:     Togglebutton
```

There is a lot of space between the text view and the toggle button.

Comment: I think thats how table layout works.  It tries to adjust to fit the columns.

Comment: Oh.. the table layout is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want extra space you should set both of their widths to `wrap_content` and wrap them in a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This Button:"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ToggleButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: From Android documentation (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html): The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

Comment: What if you wrap these two in a LinearLayout? like in the edit

Comment: Thanks. LinearLayout was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're wanting to close the gap, try `android:gravity="right"` on the TextView.

If that doesn't do it, play with setting different values for `android:layout_weight` on both the TextView and ToggleButton to balance out the horizontal spacing.

Comment: But then I have space on the left side.